# How can I solve two variable but for two separate real valued functions differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f=f(u)$ and $g=g(v)$ be two real valued functions. How can I solve

$f^{\prime \prime }(u)\left[ 1+\left( g^{\prime }(v)-\frac{\lambda u}{2}%
\right) ^{2}\right] +g^{\prime \prime }(v)\left[ 1+\left( f^{\prime }(u)+%
\frac{\lambda v}{2}\right) ^{2}\right] =0$

where $λ$ is a non-zero constant? I know how to solve ODEs but I don’t have a clue how to solve this? I know the equation must always be satisfied for all $u$ and $v$ variables. This might be thought as partial differential equation but I know less about PDEs.

Comment: Generally, to solve for two unknown functions, you need two differential equations.

Comment: Notice that the functions depend on different variables u and v. I think  f(u) and g(v) could be found somehow from this equation.

Comment: Can we assume f''(u) or g''(v) at least one must be zero? Otherwise the equation can not be satisfied for all u and v? Just an idea.

Comment: I wonder if this is separable?

Comment: For $\lambda=0$ we have $g'(v) = \tan(k v+C_1),\ \ f'(u)=\tan(k u+ C_2)$ for $k\in \mathbb{R}$